# Sort by chronological order in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

I'm a starter using Hadoop. Looking in the documentation of Apache Hadoop I've just found that data can be sorted mainly by numeric or alphabetical order. Here the link to the API's documentation:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/KeyFieldBasedComparator.html

Is it there any way I could make my data merge in chronological order?

Answer (score 0):

by default data is sorted on key in lexicographical order if you want to sort the data according to any other criteria then you need to implement secondary sort

pleas follow below link

http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/02/hadoop-how-to-do-secondary-sort-on_25.html